# Is there a way to check is the button clicked with FluentAutomation?

Tags: c#, specflow, fluentautomation

I want to check the button is clicked or not use FluentAutomation.
And there has two types about button.
One is locked, it can't be change. Just like picture but it's HTML still is input.
Another can click but I don't want to change it.
I just want to know is it clicked or not.
Is there a way to check is the button clicked?

Comment: I have no idea about how to do it.Because I don't know how to only catch what's checked in input type.

Unchecked and checked button's HTML code is:
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to check:

```
string x = I.Find("#checkboxID").Element.Attributes.Get("checked");
bool clicked = (x != null);
```